# How to create dynamic pages to a component from endpoints in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

For example, I have a component **blog-post.svelte**. This component contains the basic layout for my blog post. Then based on data of fetch endpoints, I want to create different pages from component **blog-post.svelte**.

- example.com/how-to-start-website
- example.com/how-to-eat-apple
- example.com/how-to-eat-cake

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate components dynamically with `<svelte:component>`, so you could potentially pick different components based on your current endpoint :

```
<script>
  // Import all your components here

  let myComponent = false;
  let endpoint = ; // add your code to determine your endpoint here

  switch (endpoint) {
    case 'endpoint 1':
      myComponent = EndpointComponent1;
      break;
    case 'endpoint 2':
      myComponent = EndpointComponent2;
      break;
    case 'endpoint 3':
      myComponent = EndpointComponent3;
      break;
    default:
      myComponent = DefaultEndpointComponent;
      break;
  }
</script>

<svelte:component this={myComponent} />
```

Comment: This would not add url to the page; it will just render components. What if endpoints contain 1000s of blog post data and we have to create separate page for a blog post.

Comment: Then you might want to look up [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev/), it's an application framework based on Svelte with a built-in router that should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in diving into [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev/) and SSR, it's not too difficult to implement your own simple hash routing on the client side, utilising the `<svelte:component>` special element, to achieve what you're after.

Here's a small project I threw together to show how you might go about it: https://github.com/joshmanderson/svelte-blog-hash-router-example

And here's a demo: https://svelte-blog-hash-router-example-437uuzkc5.now.sh

One caveat with that solution is that all the blog post hashes are of the form: `post-{id}` to be able to easily match the blog post route. There are ways around that of course, for example: if the current hash doesn't match any predefined routes you could *assume* that it's a blog post, then if you can't find a matching blog post you can fall back to your not found or index route. However you would want to implement that is totally up to you though.